# How to move pandas data from index to column after multiple groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, multi-index

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
token    year    uses  books
  386   xanthos  1830    3     3
  387   xanthos  1840    1     1
  388   xanthos  1840    2     2
  389   xanthos  1868    2     2
  390   xanthos  1875    1     1
```

I aggregate the rows with duplicate `token` and `years` like so:

```
dfalph = dfalph[['token','year','uses','books']].groupby(['token', 'year']).agg([np.sum])
dfalph.columns = dfalph.columns.droplevel(1)
```

which results in

```
               uses  books
token    year       
xanthos  1830    3     3
         1840    3     3
         1867    2     2
         1868    2     2
         1875    1     1
```

Instead of having the 'token' and 'year' fields in the index, I would like to return them to columns and have an integer index.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

**Method #1**: [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
>>> g
              uses  books
               sum    sum
token   year             
xanthos 1830     3      3
        1840     3      3
        1868     2      2
        1875     1      1

[4 rows x 2 columns]
>>> g = g.reset_index()
>>> g
     token  year  uses  books
                   sum    sum
0  xanthos  1830     3      3
1  xanthos  1840     3      3
2  xanthos  1868     2      2
3  xanthos  1875     1      1

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

**Method #2**: don't make the index in the first place, using [`as_index=False`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
>>> g = dfalph[['token', 'year', 'uses', 'books']].groupby(['token', 'year'], as_index=False).sum()
>>> g
     token  year  uses  books
0  xanthos  1830     3      3
1  xanthos  1840     3      3
2  xanthos  1868     2      2
3  xanthos  1875     1      1

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 8):

I differ from the accepted answer.
While there are 2 ways to do this, these will not necessarily result in same output. Specially when you are using `Grouper` in `groupby`

- `index=False`
- `reset_index()`

example `df`

```
+---------+---------+-------------+------------+
| column1 | column2 | column_date | column_sum |
+---------+---------+-------------+------------+
| A       | M       | 26-10-2018  |          2 |
| B       | M       | 28-10-2018  |          3 |
| A       | M       | 30-10-2018  |          6 |
| B       | M       | 01-11-2018  |          3 |
| C       | N       | 03-11-2018  |          4 |
+---------+---------+-------------+------------+
```

They do not work the same way.

```
df = df.groupby(
    by=[
        'column1',
        'column2',
        pd.Grouper(key='column_date', freq='M')
    ],
    as_index=False
).sum()
```

The above will give

```
+---------+---------+------------+
| column1 | column2 | column_sum |
+---------+---------+------------+
| A       | M       |          8 |
| B       | M       |          3 |
| B       | M       |          3 |
| C       | N       |          4 |
+---------+---------+------------+
```

While,

```
df = df.groupby(
    by=[
        'column1',
        'column2',
        pd.Grouper(key='column_date', freq='M')
    ]
).sum().reset_index()
```

Will give

```
+---------+---------+-------------+------------+
| column1 | column2 | column_date | column_sum |
+---------+---------+-------------+------------+
| A       | M       | 31-10-2018  |          8 |
| B       | M       | 31-10-2018  |          3 |
| B       | M       | 30-11-2018  |          3 |
| C       | N       | 30-11-2018  |          4 |
+---------+---------+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `MultiIndex` and want to reset only a specific index level you can use the parameter `level` in [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
. For example:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('one', 'a'), ('one', 'b'), ('two', 'a'), ('two', 'b')], names=['A', 'B'])
s = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1.0, 5.0), index=index, columns=['C'])

        C
A   B     
one a  1.0
    b  2.0
two a  3.0
    b  4.0
```

Reset the first level:

```
df.reset_index(level=0)
```

Output:

```
     A    C
B          
a  one  1.0
b  one  2.0
a  two  3.0
b  two  4.0
```

Reset the second level:

```
df.reset_index(level=1)
```

Output:

```
     B    C
A          
one  a  1.0
one  b  2.0
two  a  3.0
two  b  4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `drop=True`:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True)

df = df.groupby(
    by=[
        'column1',
        'column2',
        pd.Grouper(key='column_date', freq='M')
    ]
).sum().reset_index(drop=True)
```