# how to list all the data after group by and sum by making a sepreate column for each

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set  called fy2019 that contains the columns

[image]

I want to group by Name and add up the expenses based on the name. I did this. It works perfectly fine.

Expenses= (fy2019.groupby(['Name'])['Expenses'].sum()).map(int)
Expenses_2018= (fy2018.groupby(['Name'])['Expenses'].sum()).map(int)
Expenses

But, when I display the expense it comes in one column with shape(4,). How can I make it two-column after grouping and sum? And also, I want to get a list of expenses from the year 2018 and make a table that contains Name, Expenses_2019, and Expenses_2018

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move pandas data from index to column after multiple groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767900/how-to-move-pandas-data-from-index-to-column-after-multiple-groupby)

Comment: `fy2019.groupby(['Name'])['Expenses'].sum().astype(int).reset_index()`

Comment: "I have a data set called fy2019" so you have separate data-set (I guess loaded from different file) fy2018?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
data = [['Jack', 100], ['Jack', 200], ['Jum', 35],['Brad', 60], ['Brad', 50], ['Anil', 70],['Anil', 90]]  

test = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Expenses']) 

test.groupby(df.Name).sum()

test
Out[449]: 
      Expenses
Name          
Anil       160
Brad       110
Jack       300
Jum         35
```

This should work with an added column as well.

```
data = [['Jack', 0, 100], ['Jack', 200, 0], ['Jum', 35, 0],['Brad', 0, 60], ['Brad', 0, 50], ['Anil', 0, 70],['Anil', 90, 0],['Anil', 110, 0]]  

test = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Expenses_2018', 'Expenses_2019']) 

test = test.groupby(test.Name).sum()

test

      Expenses_2018  Expenses_2019
Name                              
Anil            200             70
Brad              0            110
Jack            200            100
Jum              35              0
```

Let me know if this helps or if I can modify further to help more. Thx!