# str.contains function not working for my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with 5 columns (Participants, duration_1, duration_2, duration_3, duration_4). The "Participant" column has either subjects with the IDCY or IDCO labels. FOr example: IDCY06, IDCO02,IDCY31...etc. I want to create two new dataframes: those with the IDCY and those with IDCO. I have been using the code:

```
df[df["Participant"].str.contains("IDCY")]
```

and I keep getting a keyerror code for Participants even though everything is spelled as it should be.

Is there any other method to iterate over rows and to get a new dataframe with the participants that have a set substring?

Thank you.

Comment: You mentioned you have columns "Participant**s**" (plural) but your code has `df['Participant']`.  If this is a typo, try printing the columns `print(df.columns)` and see if you have any leading or trailing spaces or not.

Comment: Sorry the name is "Participant" and I have it as "Participant" on the code and dataframe. Thank you

Comment: What is the result of `print(df.columns)`?

Comment: If you're getting a key error, changing the iteration method won't solve that problem.

Comment: After Emma's initial help, I noticed the "Participant" column does not form part of the dataframe. Before I used the code "df3=df2.groupby('Participant').agg({'current page':'first','Duration_1':'sum'})" to add all the duration_1 of the same participants since a lot of them have multiple durations for the same type. After that, the "Participant" column disappeared. Any thoughts on how to add the participant column back?

Comment: That means `Participant` is now the index. One option is to just filter the index: `df3[df3.index.str.contains("IDCY")]`

Comment: Another option is to use `as_index=False` when grouping, which will leave `Participant` as a column: `df3=df2.groupby('Participant', as_index=False).agg({'current page':'first','Duration_1':'sum'})`

Comment: Or use `reset_index()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21768034/13138364

Comment: Thank you! I had plotted a bar graph with the x axis as the participant ID (ex: IDCY06) and after I did the as_index=False, the x axis changed to just regular numbers. I have tried setting an index to plot the bar graph but it does not work.